# fork from repo A to repo B, add new branch a repo B, want to keep sync from repo A

Tags: git

I am wondering what is the best way to do the following task

> fork from repo A to repo B, add new branch and push to repo B,
>   assuming that the new branch name is unique enough that repo A will
>   never have the same one
>   - This I can do by using git clone --mirror and git push --mirror, and followed by git branch -b [new_branch_name] in repo B

Here is the question:

> We want to keep syncing from repo A, including the new changes for
>   existing and all newly created branches from repo A, to repo B, while
>   keeping the [new_branch_name] in repo B
>   - obviously git push --mirror would delete [new_branch_name] in repo B.
>
> Could we be advised what is the best way to do this?

Comment: *“obviously `git push --mirror` would delete `[new_branch_name]` in repo B.”* – It would only do that if the branch is gone locally too. But I don’t see that happenning if you update your local repository correctly using just `git fetch originalremote`.

Answer (score 0):

The fork used for making changes on a project without effect on main project.
If both of repo A and B want to always be synced together simple way is **working on a single fork**.

Comment: Yes I agree but we don't want the new branch to show up in repo A while we need it. repo A is open source while we want to make in house feature branch.

Comment: Simply you want update all exist branches and add all new branches from Repo A to Repo B?

Comment: Yes. that is the ideal. :)

Comment: Maybe you can do this, but this is not safe. Your local code become unstable. I thing you are on the wrong way. Please express your main challenge.